# Uncaught TypeError: knopkes.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

```js
let knopkes = document.querySelectorAll(`div`);
let score = document.querySelector(`#calc`);
let septyni = document.querySelector(`#semke`);
let astuoni = document.querySelector(`#astuoni`);
let devyni = document.querySelector(`#devyni`);
let dalyba = document.querySelector(`#dalyba`);
let keturi = document.querySelector(`#keturi`);
let penki = document.querySelector(`#penki`);
let sesi = document.querySelector(`#sesi`);
let daugyba = document.querySelector(`#daugyba`);
let vienas = document.querySelector(`#vienas`);
let du = document.querySelector(`#du`);
let trys = document.querySelector(`#trys`);
let minus = document.querySelector(`#minus`);
let nulis = document.querySelector(`#nulis  `);
let taskas = document.querySelector(`#taskas`);
let lygybe = document.querySelector(`#lygybe`);
let sudetis = document.querySelector(`#sudetis`);



knopkes.addEventListener(`click`,function() {
    score.textContent = astuoni.textContent;
});
```

```css
#container  {
    width:500px;
    background-color:aqua;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius:15%;
cursor: pointer;} 

#calc {
    width:500px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 110, 141);
    text-align: end;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius:5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calc">0</div>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id="semke">7</div>
        <div id="astuoni">8</div>
        <div id="devyni">9</div>
        <div id="dalyba">÷</div>
        <div id="keturi">4</div>
        <div id="penki">5</div>
        <div id="sesi">6</div>
        <div id="daugyba">X</div>
        <div id="vienas">1</div>
        <div id="du">2</div>
        <div id="trys">3</div>
        <div id="minus">-</div>
        <div id="nulis">0</div>
        <div id="taskas">.</div>
        <div id="lygybe">=</div>
        <div id="sudetis">+</div>
    </div>
    
<p>para</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, why do I get Uncaught TypeError: knopkes.addEventListener is not a function ? If i change the knopkes variable to any of the numbers it works. But it doesnt work when I try to apply the eventListener to every button at once? Is this a bug or something? Because it works with literally every single one of the buttons. But it doesnt seem to work for the "knopke" variable, which chooses   every button at once so I could save time by not writing an eventListener for every button? Ty in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not an element, and therefore has no `addEventListener` function.

You have to iterate through each element in the list instead:

```js
let knopkes = document.querySelectorAll(`div`);
let score = document.querySelector(`#calc`);
let septyni = document.querySelector(`#semke`);
let astuoni = document.querySelector(`#astuoni`);
let devyni = document.querySelector(`#devyni`);
let dalyba = document.querySelector(`#dalyba`);
let keturi = document.querySelector(`#keturi`);
let penki = document.querySelector(`#penki`);
let sesi = document.querySelector(`#sesi`);
let daugyba = document.querySelector(`#daugyba`);
let vienas = document.querySelector(`#vienas`);
let du = document.querySelector(`#du`);
let trys = document.querySelector(`#trys`);
let minus = document.querySelector(`#minus`);
let nulis = document.querySelector(`#nulis  `);
let taskas = document.querySelector(`#taskas`);
let lygybe = document.querySelector(`#lygybe`);
let sudetis = document.querySelector(`#sudetis`);



knopkes.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(`click`,function(e) {
    score.textContent = e.target.textContent;
}));
```

```css
#container  {
    width:500px;
    background-color:aqua;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container > div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius:15%;
cursor: pointer;} 

#calc {
    width:500px;
    background-color: rgb(58, 110, 141);
    text-align: end;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius:5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calc">0</div>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id="semke">7</div>
        <div id="astuoni">8</div>
        <div id="devyni">9</div>
        <div id="dalyba">÷</div>
        <div id="keturi">4</div>
        <div id="penki">5</div>
        <div id="sesi">6</div>
        <div id="daugyba">X</div>
        <div id="vienas">1</div>
        <div id="du">2</div>
        <div id="trys">3</div>
        <div id="minus">-</div>
        <div id="nulis">0</div>
        <div id="taskas">.</div>
        <div id="lygybe">=</div>
        <div id="sudetis">+</div>
    </div>
    
<p>para</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey one more question if you got some time to answer me, whats the best way to get the textContent of the number that I clicked it?  `this` doesnt work since it chooses every single one, can you help out a newbie? Thanks!

Comment: @edga9966 You can get the event target. I've updated my answer to incorporate it.